# Why sentinel-2 bands contain values around 25000?

Tags: python, rasterio, sentinel2

I am trying to process .jp2 files using Python. Data came from sentinel-2 as it is written in MTD_MSIL1C.xml file.

When I read files using rasterio library I receive numpy arrays with values greater than 20k.

`img = rasterio.open('some_band.jp2', driver='JP2OpenJPEG').read(1)`

for the following command
`img.max()`
I have got such value `23526`

GDAL version == 3.0.2
Rasterio version == 1.2.6

You can only post once every 90 minutes.

I would like to visualize .jp2 files. For that I need values in range 0 and 255. Simple normalization and multiplying by 255 result in dark image.

I tried to divide image by 3000 and pass it to matplotlib. Resultant image looks well, but why it is so?

Also I tried this command which produced results in range of 0 and 255
`gdal_translate -scale 0 3000 0 255 -ot Byte`

Comment: I have found that when there are many clouds in the image values can be that big(20000+). But still, I do not know how I should have known that value 3000?